# An automated sandbox refresh caused the loss of data

Tags: sandbox

Our sandbox got refreshed friday afternoon by an "automated process". Is there any way to recover the lost data ? Also, the integration to Clarizen is gone and I no longer can connect it.

Thanks,

Regards,

Amir

Comment: You have to log a case, see this SE post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107431/attempting-official-deploy-process-with-single-sandbox-may-reset-remove-all-exis/107434#107434

Comment: Hi Fred, I will contact them but, since the refresh happened last friday, do you think there's still a chance to get the data back ? I heard about the "3 days rule"...

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this issue is to log a case at Salesforce. They usually revert the changes if you log the case within 72 hours (no guarantees) and they may extend this timeframe for you.